# Object disappearing whenever it's not selected

Tags: objects

[image: Example]

My object disappears whenever it's not selected. It's not hidden, I'm not in local view... I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please upload a full image of blender, I mean include toll bars

Comment: We need more information, can you upload the Blend: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Does the mesh has edges or only vertices?

Comment: Here's the .blend file. And yes, the mesh has edges. http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=47475

Edit: Fixed it. See below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out. Somehow I ended up duplicating all vertices for that mesh, which caused rendering issues apparently. Removing duplicates fixes it.

Comment: but how do u remove the duplicated? I tried W- remove doubles, doesnt do it.